# Import Unity file in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unity-game-engine, src

I am having trouble loading a `Unity` file in my `React` project. I thought if I add the file in `index.html` I would be able to use `UnityLoader` anywhere in the project as shown below:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="UnityLoader.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unity.js

```
class Unity extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="unity">
                {UnityLoader.instantiate('unity', 'unity/index.html')}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying `UnityLoader` is undefined.

Do I need to use some sort of

```
import { UnityLoader } from 'UnityLoader'
```

in `Unity.js`? The issue is that `UnityLoader` is an external JS file and does not export anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not installing [React-Unity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unity-webgl) via npm and then import it into your component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Unity } from 'react-unity-webgl';


export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className="app">
      <Unity src="Build/myGame.json" />
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add a script tag to load the UnityLoader.js file, exported by Unity in your base html file.

```
<script src="build_unity/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script> 
<script src="compiled/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought about that but wasn't sure how reliable it was. But I guess that makes the most sense. Thanks

Comment: I hope it works. There is another unity npm package as well. But I believe this is the way to make it work.

Comment: I am having problems with the second step to load the UnityLoader. I am using Create-react-app and tried to add `<script src="relativePathToUnityLoader></script>` to public/index.html. But perhaps this is the wrong file? Since it still says: `React-Unity-Webgl error:The UnityLoader was not defined...`. I also tried to do a regular `import "relativePathToUnityLoader";` in the .js file. This instead gives me `'webAssembly' is not defined, unexpected use of screen` and so on